# Qt/C++ mock QSettings

Tags: c++, qt

I a trying to write unit tests for a settings manager class which does not only store the settings but also does validation, so no I am not only testing the functionality of the QSettings class. Its about the actual management implementation.
My problem at this point is that I do not want to handle files because those will be poluted with every test and resetting them will be costly. I saw that the QSettings class offers to register a custom format registration:

```
QSettings::Format QSettings::registerFormat(const QString &extension, QSettings::ReadFunc readFunc, QSettings::WriteFunc writeFunc, Qt::CaseSensitivity caseSensitivity = Qt::CaseSensitive)
```

Example for WriteFunc:

```
bool myWriteFunc(QIODevice &device, const QSettings::SettingsMap &map);
```

My idea is to somehow have QSettings operate on QBuffer instead of a QIOFileDevice. But I do not find a way of forcing QSettings to use a different child of QIODevice. Am I overseeing something?